# Android Clipboard missing in Chooser

Tags: java, android, android-intent, clipboard

When I want to share basic plaintext in my app, the option to copy it in my clipboard does not show up in the chooserlist. Is there something wrong with my code? Or has my device a wrong setup?

```
String code = getXMLCode();

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, code);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, getString(R.string.shareXMLCode)));



public String getXMLCode(){...}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android does not have a "copy to clipboard" option as part of `ACTION_SEND`. Certain apps, like Google Drive, might offer such a feature.

cketti recently wrote [a blog post](http://cketti.de/2016/06/15/share-url-to-clipboard/) about how you can add your own "copy to clipboard" option to your own `ACTION_SEND` requests. In a nutshell, you use `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS` to add another option to the chooser, one that points to your own activity that will offer "copy to clipboard".